# Getting every other line empty on output

Tags: c

I have a problem with getting every other line empty on output with this code. The desired output is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1354365/

While I get: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1356669/

Does anyone have an idea of why I'm getting these empty lines on every other line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fp; 
FILE *fw; 


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char buffer[100];
char *fileName = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
char **output = calloc(10, sizeof(char*));
char **outputBuffer = calloc(10, sizeof(char*));

fw = fopen("calvin.txt", "w+");

for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
    {
        output[i] = malloc(100);
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < 12; x++){
        sprintf(fileName,"part_%02d-%02d", x, y);
        fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");

        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Kan ikke åpne den filen(finnes ikke/rettigheter)\n");
        }
        else if(fp != NULL){

            memset(buffer, 0, 100); 
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ 
                outputBuffer[i] = malloc(100);
            }


            fread(buffer, 1, 100, fp); 


            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                if(buffer[i] == '\0')
                {
                    buffer[i] = ' ';
                }
                else if(buffer[i] == '\n')
                {
                    buffer[i] = ' ';
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
                strncpy(outputBuffer[i], buffer + i * 10, 10);

                strncat(output[i], outputBuffer[i]+1, 11);


            }                       
        }

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("%s\n", output[i]);

    }

}
fclose(fp);
free(fileName);

}
```

Comment: Was your input file created on Windows?  If so, then your lines may be ending with \r\n instead of just \n, and your code appears to only be checking for \n.

Comment: Change this: "rb" to this: "r" and see if that puts you closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: I made the file on Ubuntu, and I've tried with both "r" and "rb". Seems to be no difference

Comment: I left the links as is, as they would be difficult to incorporate into the post (ASCII art).

Comment: There are many things you need to fix about your code.  For once, you keep allocating all the time and never dispose of the memory.

Are there really 6 vertical parts and 12 horizontal parts (total of 72 files)? 

Why do you copy from buffer to outputBuffer to then concat in output?

Comment: Had to relocate all the lines properly from the buffer first, and then concat them into the output. This is just an assignment for school wich I've had little time with, so much of the code could be better.

Comment: Tried on my school-laptop today, and everything seems to be fine. So I get the desired output on a 64bit linux, but not 32 bit linux. Weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading correcting from the file. On the first image in the beginning you have:

```
      o ""oo    " o o o
```

on the second

```
      ""oo     o o o
```

That does not make a lot of sense because it is the first line. It is not related to empty lines since we are talking about the first line.

It seems that you are reading `-2` characters from the left so " prints over o the other " on the ' ' ect..

Try this away, may not be the most efficient solution:

```
int read(char *file)
{
     FILE *fp = NULL;         
     int size = 0, pos = 0,i;
     fp = fopen(file,"r");
     if (!fp) return 0;

     for(; ((getc(fp))!=EOF);  size++); // Count the number of elements in the file

     fclose(fp);


     char buffer[size];

     fp = fopen(file,"r");

     if (!fp) return 0;

     while((buffer[pos++]=getc(fp))!=EOF); // Saving the chars into the buffer

     for(i = 0; i < pos; i++)              // print them.
       printf("%c",buffer[i]);

    fclose(fp);
    return 1;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part seems problematic:

```
           strncpy(outputBuffer[i], buffer + i * 10, 10);

           strncat(output[i], outputBuffer[i]+1, 11);
```

1) Why is it necessary to use the extra `outputBuffer` step?

2) You know that `strncpy()` isn't guaranteed to null-terminate the string it copies.

3) More significantly, `output[i]` hasn't been initialized, so `strncat()` will concatenate the string after whatever junk is already in there.  **If you use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` when creating each `output[i]`, that might help.**  It's even possible that your `output[i]` variables are what hold your extra newline.

4) Even if initialized to an empty string, you could easily overflow `output[i]`, since you're looping 12 times and writing up to 11 characters to it.  11 * 12 + 1 for the null terminator = 133 bytes written to a 100-byte array.

In general, unless this is a class assignment that requires use of `malloc()`, I don't understand why you aren't just declaring your variables once, at the start of the program and zeroing them out at the start of each loop:

```
char fileName[10];
char output[10][100];
char outputBuffer[10][100];
```

And, as stated by others, your allocating a bunch of memory and not trying to free it up.  Allocate it once outside of your loop or just skip the allocation step and declare them directly.